# How do I embed a visualforce page into a knowledge article?

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, lightning-knowledge, video, embedded

I created a Visualforce page in order to embed a video that is hosted within our own company's digital asset software.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false">
    <iframe width="560" height="315"
        src="//embed.widencdn.net/video/widen/axvgijz14c?u=lkuotr"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Now I want to add this visualforce page to a knowledge article. I found a Salesforce support article that says you can do this, but I'm not following the instructions. There's some sort of video ID referenced in their sample code:

For example, create a Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false">
    <iframe width="560" height="315"
        src="http//myvideo.provider.com/embed/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.VideoID}"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Then, with the HTML editor, authors can reference videos using this code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="315"
    src="https://<salesforce_instance>/apex/Video?videoID=12345"
    width="560">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to just guess where this support article can be found? Please **[edit]** your post to link to it so we can see what you are looking at. :)

Comment: The videoId is just an example so the underlying VF page can be reused in multiple knowledge articles, each referencing a different video.  If you only have a single video, you can skip the parameter altogether

Comment: see this [Salesforce Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_html_editor_videos.htm&type=5) on embedding videos in Knowledge using a list of approved providers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a custom video provider other than an [approved SFDC one](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_html_editor_videos.htm&type=5)

then the SFDC Help on how to do this is [shown here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_admin_tricks_examples_videos.htm&type=5) and is what you referenced in the OP

Now, assume your VF page is called `MyCoolVideo`:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false">
    <iframe width="560" height="315"
        src="//embed.widencdn.net/video/widen/axvgijz14c?u=lkuotr"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Then in the Knowledge article HTML editor you simply need

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="315"
    src="https://<salesforce_instance>/apex/MyCoolVideo"
    width="560">
</iframe>
```

The SF Help page used a videoId parameter so your VF page could be reused across many Knowledge articles each referring to different videos. This depends on a predictable naming structure for your videos so you might be able to do this by changing your VF page to:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false">
    <iframe width="560" height="315"
        src="//embed.widencdn.net/video/widen/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.VideoID}?u=lkuotr"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
    </iframe>
</apex:page>
```

and the reference in the Knowledge Article to:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="315"
    src="https://<salesforce_instance>/apex/MyCoolVideo?VideoID=axvgijz14c"
    width="560">
</iframe>
```

Comment: The article I was referencing is located at: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_admin_tricks_examples_videos.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

Comment: @LoriRott - Yep, I found that and linked to it in my answer